# C# DirectSound - Capture buffers not continuous

Tags: c#, api, audio, directx, sampling

I'm trying to capture raw data from my line-in using DirectSound.

My problem is that, from a buffer to another the data are just inconsistent, if for example I capture a sine I see a jump from my last buffer and the new one. To detected this I use a graph widget to draw the first 500 elements of the last buffer and the 500 elements from the new one:

[image: snapshot]
http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/206/demodsnap.jpg

I initialized my buffer this way:

```
   format = new WaveFormat {
            SamplesPerSecond = 44100,
            BitsPerSample = (short)bitpersample,           
            Channels = (short)channels,
            FormatTag = WaveFormatTag.Pcm
        };

        format.BlockAlign = (short)(format.Channels * (format.BitsPerSample / 8));
        format.AverageBytesPerSecond = format.SamplesPerSecond * format.BlockAlign;

        _dwNotifySize = Math.Max(4096, format.AverageBytesPerSecond / 8);
        _dwNotifySize -= _dwNotifySize % format.BlockAlign;
        _dwCaptureBufferSize = NUM_BUFFERS * _dwNotifySize; // my capture buffer
        _dwOutputBufferSize = NUM_BUFFERS * _dwNotifySize / channels; // my output buffer
```

I set my notifications one at half the buffer and one at the end:

```
     _resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _notify = new Notify(_dwCapBuffer);

        bpn1 = new BufferPositionNotify();
        bpn1.Offset = ((_dwCapBuffer.Caps.BufferBytes) / 2) - 1;
        bpn1.EventNotifyHandle = _resetEvent.SafeWaitHandle.DangerousGetHandle();
        bpn2 = new BufferPositionNotify();
        bpn2.Offset = (_dwCapBuffer.Caps.BufferBytes) - 1;
        bpn2.EventNotifyHandle = _resetEvent.SafeWaitHandle.DangerousGetHandle();

        _notify.SetNotificationPositions(new BufferPositionNotify[] { bpn1, bpn2 });

        observer.updateSamplerStatus("Events listener initialization complete!\r\n");
```

And here is how I process the events.

```
/* Process thread */
private void eventReceived()
        {
            int offset = 0;
            _dwCaptureThread = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
            {

                _dwCapBuffer.Start(true);

                while (isReady)
                {
                    _resetEvent.WaitOne(); // Notification received
                    /* Read the captured buffer */
                    Array read = _dwCapBuffer.Read(offset, typeof(short), LockFlag.None, _dwOutputBufferSize - 1);

                    observer.updateTextPacket("Buffer: " + count.ToString() + " # " + read.GetValue(read.Length - 1).ToString() + " # " + read.GetValue(0).ToString() + "\r\n");
                    /* Print last/new part of the buffer to the debug graph */
                    short[] graphData = new short[1001];
                    Array.Copy(read, graphData, 1000);

                    db.SetBufferDebug(graphData, 500);
                    observer.updateGraph(db.getBufferDebug());



                    offset = (offset + _dwOutputBufferSize) % _dwCaptureBufferSize;

                    /* Out buffer not used */
                    /*_dwDevBuffer.Write(0, read, LockFlag.EntireBuffer);

                    _dwDevBuffer.SetCurrentPosition(0);
                    _dwDevBuffer.Play(0, BufferPlayFlags.Default);*/

                }

                _dwCapBuffer.Stop();
            });
            _dwCaptureThread.Start();

        }
```

Any advise? I'm sure I'm failing somewhere in the event processing, but I cant find where.

I had developed the same application using the WaveIn API and it worked well.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Look very closely at the last parameter of _dwCapBuffer.Read
its type is , params int[] ranks
I have the same problem and just found out about this. I hope this helps both you and me.

Comment: I kind of solved it, it was an error in how I printed out the graph :-/
In any case I've still have an incogruens between the buffers but is really minimal. Now I've switched to NAudio library and it works perfectly!